# How can I line up radio buttons horizontally rather than vertically?

Tags: cakephp, radio-button

I have been looking at the [Cookbook - 7.3.3 Automagic Form Elements](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1390/Automagic-Form-Elements) trying to find a way for radio buttons to line up horizontally rather than vertically.  I have been looking at the `'div' => 'class_name' $options` also the `$options[‘between’]`, `$options[‘separator’]` and `$options[‘after’]` but have been unsuccessful.  Is there a "cake" way of doing this?

```
<?=$form->input('Product Type', array(
     'type' => 'radio',
     'id' => $tire['ProductType']['id'],
     'name' => $tire['ProductType']['id'],
     'options' => array(2=>'Tire Manufacturer', 7=>'Rim Manufacturer '),
));?>
```

The of equivalent this

```
<label>Product Type</label>
<div style="padding-top:5px;">
    <input type="radio" name="data[Manufacturer][product_type_id]" value="<?=$tire['ProductType']['id']?>"> Tire Manufacturer &nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="radio" name="data[Manufacturer][product_type_id]" value="<?=$wheel['ProductType']['id']?>"> Rim Manufacturer
</div>
```

Comment: CakePHP 3 UPDATE: The separator, between, and legend options have been removed from radio(). You can use templates to change the wrapping HTML now. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34730620/cakephp-3-changing-the-radio-input-template)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to put each radio button inside an 'LI' tag, and then apply CSS styles to the 'UL' that tells it to show 'LI' tags horizontally instead of vertically. You can find a lot of horizontal list designs [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/listamatic/).

Comment: Thanks for the answer Mike.  I still haven't found a "cake" way of doing this so I just went with with a checkbox.

Comment: That's because the responsible for that styling behavior isn't cake, but CSS

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:
Inside your view file (viewfile.ctp):

```
<div>  
<?php  
echo $this->Form->create('changeRegion');  
$options=array('US'=>'U.S.','CA'=>'Canada', 'FN'=>'International');  
$attributes=array('legend'=>false, 'label'=>false, 'value'=>'US', 'class'=>'locRad');  
echo $form->radio('subLocation',$options,$attributes);  
echo $this->Form->end();  
?>  
<div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```

Make sure *'label'=>false* and *'legend'=>false* are set in your attributes.

In your stylesheet:

```
input[type=radio] {
float:left;
margin:0px;
width:20px;
}

form#changeRegionStdForm input[type=radio].locRad {
margin:3px 0px 0px 3px; 
float:none;
}
```

I fought this forever because of the default CakePHP style rule for *input[type=radio]* (inside the *app/webroot/css/cake.generic.css* file) was always taking precedence. I generated another rule to specifically pick out the radio group in question by referencing the form along with the radio input rule appended with the class name *(form#changeRegionStdForm input[type=radio].locRad)*.  I initially did this with the *form#* rule listed before the *input[type=*.  Only when I moved it after the *input[type=* did the radio buttons line up horizontally.

I hope this makes sense and actually helps someone else.

Answer (score 2):

I found this post very late. But i thought others might stumble upon this like i did now.

Try something like this:

```
<ul id="hMenu"><li>
<?php
$attributes=array('legend'=>false, 'separator'=>'</li><li>', 'label'=>false);
$form->input('Product Type',$options, $attributes);
?>
</li></ul>
```

Now style the id hMenu. That should solve this problem.

This without any styling gives verical radio buttons. But if you use css styling on **ul** and **li** you could literally make it stand on its head! :)

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
$form->input('Product Type', array(
 'type' => 'radio',
 'id' => $tire['ProductType']['id'],
 'name' => $tire['ProductType']['id'],
 'options' => array(2=>'Tire Manufacturer', 7=>'Rim Manufacturer '),
 ***********************
 'seperator' => '<br />'
 ***********************
));
```

which result look like this :

```
<label>Product Type</label>
<div style="padding-top:5px;">
  <input type="radio" name="data[Manufacturer][product_type_id]" value="<?=$tire['ProductType']['id']?>"> Tire Manufacturer &nbsp;&nbsp;
  <br />
  <input type="radio" name="data[Manufacturer][product_type_id]" value="<?=$wheel['ProductType']['id']?>"> Rim Manufacturer
</div>
```

Comment: Spelling for separator would be "separator" not "seperator"

Answer (score 2):

Try this, I got my code working through this..

```
<ul id = "navlist">
    <fieldset>
      <legend><?php echo __('Insert User'); ?></legend>

        <li><?php //echo $this->Form->input('Site', array('options' => $arraycharges));?></li>

        <li><?php echo $this->Form->input('MobileApp', array('options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User')));?></li>

        <li><?php echo $this->Form->input('Location', array('options' => array('admin' => 'Admin', 'user' => 'User')));?></li>

    <li><?php echo $this->Form->end(__('GO')); ?></li>

    </fieldset>
 </ul>
```

in the style sheet add the following..

```
#navlist li {
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You an follow like this :

```
<ul>
<li style="width: 200px;float: left;list-style: none">
    <?php
    $attributes=array(
        'legend'=>false,
        'after'=>'</li>',
        'separator'=>'</li><li style="width: 200px;float: left;list-style: none">',
    );
    echo $this->Form->radio('xyz_name',$myOptions,$attributes);
    ?>
     </li>
</ul>
```